# Show that the matrix $A$ is diagonalisable over $\mathbb C$ if $A^m = A$ for some positive integer m.

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $A$ is a $n \times n$ matrix and $A^m = A$ holds for some positive integer $m$, then show that $A$ is diagonalisable over $\mathbb C$. (There is no other additional relation given between $m$ and $n$).

How can I proceed?Is it something related to Cayley-Hamilton theorem?Please help me.

Comment: Assuming you talk about stuff in $\Bbb C$. The polynomial $x^m-x$ has distinct roots, because it's coprime with its derivative $mx^{m-1}-1$. Hence, the minimal polynomial must have distinct roots too.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I don't have any concept of minimal polynomial.Please suggest an easy one to digest.

Comment: I won't, because I don't think it's possible. (how do you know Hamilton-Cayley but not the thing which is right after it?)

Comment: Is it even true? 2 * 2 matrix $A$ which represents rotation of plane by 90 degrees is not diagonalisable. However $A^4=E$ and $A^5=A$.

Comment: @lesnik If the field is $\mathbb{C}$...

Comment: @G.Sassatelli what will happen if $n > m$?If $n-m = r$ then we have $r+1$ zero's as roots of the characteristics polynomial by Cayley-Hamilton theorem.Now what can I conclude from here?

Comment: @alex.jordan If we are talking about $\mathbb C$ then I do not understand the question at all. Isn't every square matrix over $\mathbb C$ diagonalisable?

Comment: @lesnik No, use Jordan canonical form. For example, $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ is not diagonalizable.

Comment: @Stahl. Thank you. Sorry for stupid question.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, the matrix will only be diagonalisable over the algebraic closure of the ground field or if it already contains all roots of unity.

The polynomial $T^m-T\in\Bbbk[T]$ annihilates $A$. The roots of this polynomial are pairwise distinct, they are $0$ and the $(m-1)$st roots of unity. It follows that the minimal polynomial of $A$ has pairwise distinct roots, hence $A$ is diagonalisable.

Comment: +1 but depending on the field, the polynomial may not split, or may have repeated roots. I assume OP meant over $\mathbb{C}$ though.

Comment: @alex.jordan: Good point, I also expected him to be working over $\Bbb C$.